# Parts of a nested if statement not being reached

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the `highestOrderLowestTradeVersion` lines in this if-statement below are not being hit; when debugging, the aforementioned variable never exists in the if-statement context. Even if the final two if-statements below are true, it simply ignores the `highestOrderLowestTradeVersion` lines. I've tried moving the variable declaration higher in the list, not initialising it, and initialising it separately after declaring it, but I still can't get a value for that variable. Is there anything obviously wrong in my code below?

```
int latestOrderVersion;
int latestTradeVersion;

int lowestOrderVersion = 0;
int lowestOrderHighestTradeVersion = 0;

int highestOrderVersion = 0;
int highestOrderHighestTradeVersion = 0;
int highestOrderLowestTradeVersion = 0;

foreach (DataRow filterResult2 in filterResults2.Rows)
{
    latestOrderVersion = Convert.ToInt32(filterResult2["OrderVersion"]);
    latestTradeVersion = Convert.ToInt32(filterResult2["TradeVersion"]);

    if (lowestOrderVersion == 0 || latestOrderVersion < lowestOrderVersion)
    {
        lowestOrderVersion = latestOrderVersion;

        if (lowestOrderHighestTradeVersion == 0 || lowestOrderHighestTradeVersion < latestTradeVersion)
        {
            lowestOrderHighestTradeVersion = latestTradeVersion;
        }
    }


    if (highestOrderVersion == 0 || latestOrderVersion > highestOrderVersion || latestOrderVersion == highestOrderVersion)
    {
        if (latestOrderVersion != highestOrderVersion)
        {
            highestOrderVersion = latestOrderVersion;
            highestOrderLowestTradeVersion = 0;    // never gets hit
        }

        if (highestOrderHighestTradeVersion == 0 || latestTradeVersion < highestOrderHighestTradeVersion)
        {
            highestOrderLowestTradeVersion = latestTradeVersion;    // never gets hit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Final two... there are a lot of if statements, and the "highestOrderTradeVersion" variable shows up a lot.  So it's difficult to interpret which lines of code you're actually referring to.  Try commenting them...

Comment: are you sure you run this version of the code? do a clean solution (make sure the bin/obj folder are empty) then rebuild everything. Retry after that.

Comment: That looks for me a typical de-aligment between your pdb files and your current cs class. Which means you need to rebuild your entire application in order to debug properly. A Batch build helps as well. Try also to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: No idea why you are not using latestOrderVersion >= highestOrderVersion  instead of latestOrderVersion > highestOrderVersion || latestOrderVersion == highestOrderVersion

Comment: `if ((latestTradeVersion  >= highestOrderHighestTradeVersion
      && highestOrderHighestTradeVersion  != 0
      && latestOrderVersion == highestOrderVersion)
    || (highestOrderVersion != 0
      && latestOrderVersion <= highestOrderVersion 
      && latestOrderVersion  != highestOrderVersion))`

Then neither of those statements will be executed, this tells us that a. you need print statements and b. your logic is too complex
which means this will be hard to debug in an IDE, impossible to debug on StackOverflow

Comment: @ChrisCM Thanks - I've added a couple of comments to highlight which lines are never hit.

I should also note that I migrated this logic from VB, and all of the numbers match up fine compared to running it in VB, except for the highestOrderLowestTradeVersion, which is being ignored.

Comment: foreach (DataRow filterResult2 in filterResults2.Rows) <-I think there is an error you cant filterResult2 is already defined as datatable.......

Comment: @TonyWu That's a very bad idea, but not actually a compiler error.

Comment: @duney You should use another name for the DataRow inside the foreach statement.

Comment: @TonyWu That side of things is ok - the DataTable is plural; the DataTable is singular.

Comment: @Fredou Thanks for your suggestion - I've tried this but I'm having the same issue

Comment: @duney Ohhhh... I didn't see the 's' there, sorry. Did you try to set a breakpoint on the if-statment?

Comment: @TonyWu - I tried to set a breakpoint on the if-statement, and I even set a breakpoint on the errant lines in question (the lines I commented above) but when I debug, the breakpoint just moves to the end of the foreach loop, completely ignoring the line it want it to hit!

By the way, point taken regarding why I'm not using >=. I migrated this over from VB and should tidy up that side of things.

Comment: @duney Did you try MessageBox.Show() in WinForm or Console.WriteLine() in Console Application to show the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are under a configuration with optimization turn ON.

You are never using this variable so the compiler remove it when it get compiled.

Default setting in Debug mode is OFF

Default setting in Release mode is ON

Turn off optimization or use it somewhere else.

Project -> Property -> Build -> uncheck `Optimize code`

Comment: I noticed that before you made an edit, you mentioned my solution possibly being in release mode - this was the problem. I don't know why it was in that mode but I've changed it back (which I assume in turn, unchecked the optimize code option) and the code works fine. Thanks for this nugget of information, and please mention debug/release mode in your answer!

Comment: @duney, updated my answer with the release/debug information